# Is it safe to change the default umask from 0000 on WSL?

Tags: directory

If it is safe to do that, how do i change the default umask?

If its not recommended, is there any way I can change the dir listings to not be all solid colors?

Comment: ahh good point i am on WSL and should have mentioned that.  Ok, that probably explains it then.

Comment: Colours in Ubuntu in Windows 10 (WSL) should be identical to those in Ubuntu in Linux. In both systems they can be set in `~/.bashrc`. That said I ran into problems converting Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 in Windows 10 so I'm just using Ubuntu 16.04 there.

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally safe, as some applications might assume `umask` to be `0000`.

For example, when installing extensions to `vscode-server` running in wsl (from standard vscode in win), it fails on file permissions when trying to move files from temporary location.

But if you keep that in mind, you can safely set umask to whatever you want, and if you encounter any program failing because of that, you just switch back to `0000` (thats how I do it, dont kill me lol).